# Using tryCatch to bypass the error messages with read.zoo in a loop

Tags: r, try-catch, zoo

I am trying condition handling and recovery for the first time in R. I want to use `read.zoo` function in a loop to read a number of csv files with two different time formats, say format 1 and format 2. So obviously when I am using format1 in read.zoo to read a csv file in which times are in format 2 then it would give me an error, so I want to bypass that error message and want to try the format 2 inside `read.zoo` function. I am trying something like,

```
my.zoo <- tryCatch(expr = read.zoo(my.csv, format = format1),
                   error = read.zoo(my.csv, format = format2)
```

But I am always getting the error message about the time format regardless of time format. I am not sure if I am using the `tryCatch` function properly or if there is any other way to do it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather than relying on an error, why not read a few lines of `my.csv` to decide on the correct format, and then evaluate correctly the first time? This seems like a better approach to programming in general.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I have 100s of csv files and it's a kinda urgent. Beside I always wanted to try condition handling and recovery in R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recovery has to be wrapped into the `error` function in order for `tryCatch` to operate properly, you can try something like this instead:

```
my.zoo = tryCatch(
             expr = read.zoo(my.csv, format = format1), 
             error = function(e) read.zoo(my.csv, format = format2)
          )
```